# I need to add a second ip in my instance.

Tags: google-compute-engine

I have an instance with a fixed IP, I need to insert a second IP to configure my DNS for hosting a website, how to configure this second IP on eth1?
I tried to enter an IP but I can not put in the same instance. 
I use google-compute-engine.
tks!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

you can create a target pool and add your instance to it. This will create a "second external address" for your instance, and create a forwarding rule to it.

Comment: @George: How did you've succeed that? I'm trying to do the same thing but without any success. Could you give more details?